# Using ObservableCollections for Master Detail in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, observablecollection, master-detail

Using MVVM in a Silverlight project, I would like to be able to take advantage of the INotifyPropertyChanged interface by using ObservableCollections as the source of the data for a Master/Detail configuration.  For the source of the Master list, I would like to use an ObservableCollection that retrieves a minimum number of fields from my database to minimixe loading time, and a different ObservableCollection for my Detail view that includes all fields for editing.  Doing this with two different ObservableCollections seems to defeat the INotifyPropertyChanged advantage of using ObservableCollection since the changes are being made to a different ObservableCollection than the one used for the Master List.  Is there a way to minimize data loading time for the list and still take advantage of INotifyPropertyChanged?

Answer (score 0):

ObservableCollections notify upon changes in the collection - as in add/remove. They do not handle properties within the objects. The objects themselves have to implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

Objects added to the collections are added by reference. That means that if you update the object...it is updated. It won't make any difference which/how many lists contain the object.